# How to display current data from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic2

I'm able to login, logout and display logged in user information from localStorage, however if i logout and login again with different user app displays information of previous user! this should not happen as i can see new user data in localStorage. New data displays correctly if i refresh the page manually!

I need this app to display currently logged in user's data as it's already available in localStorage..

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('menu', {
    url: '/side-menu',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'menuCtrl'
  })

  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })

  .state('menu.welcome', {
    url: '/welcome',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
        controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/user-type')

});
```

**Login:**
Here i'm authenticating user through web service, which sends back user object in JSON format which is being stored in localStorage with key 'user' and it works fine.

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$http', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $http) {
        $scope.user = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
        $scope.login = function(){
            var apiUrl = "...";
            return $http.post(apiUrl, $scope.user).then(function(response){
                window.localStorage.setItem('user', angular.toJson(response.data));
                $state.go('menu.welcome');
            });
        };
    }
])
```

**Logout:**
Here i'm logging out user by removing 'user' JSON object from localStorage, and redirecting him back to login state, and it works fine.

```
.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.user = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
        $scope.logout = function(){
            // here i'm removing user from localStorage
            window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
            $state.go('login');
        };
    }
])
```

**Menu:**
Here i'm displaying user info which is sent from 'menuCtrl' (it's not updating logged in user's data here even if it's available in localStorage)

```
<h3 id="menu-heading1" class="left-menu-headings">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h3>
<h4 id="menu-heading2" class="left-menu-headings">{{user.email}}</h4>
```

I already tried following in logout function with no success:

```
$window.localStorage.clear();
$ionicHistory.clearCache();
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();
```

Any idea why it's not displaying current data from localStorage?

Comment: Maybe set the pages to not be cached in routing configuration? Also if you just localStorage get from console do you see the object?

Comment: Yes, i can see updated key and value in chrome developer -> application -> local Storage

Comment: i temporarily resolved it using `$window.location.reload(true);` on logout, i will report back if i found some solution to refresh scope of all controllers on login..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ion view enter to define your user

```
$scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
        $scope.user = angular.fromJson(localStorage.get("user"));
    });
```

Remove the set from the controller declaration.
This will make the user get loaded each time it enters and not each time the controller gets initialized

Comment: it worked like a charm! thanks - @misha130, it will be better if i can do it from service?

Comment: I guess you could $broadcast from a service or to a service to signal a refresh.

Comment: any code hint will be appreciated.. :) for example: 
`.factory('UserFactory', function(){
 var getUser = function(){
  return angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
 };
 return {
  getUser: getUser,
 };
})`

Answer (score 0):

I have a wild guess, based on your controller name, that "menuCtl" actually lives through the reloging, so it never gets re-initialized. You should add some console.logs around the

```
$scope.user = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

To see if it is getting called the 2nd time when you relogin. If not, you may have a number of options to follow, for example, add event listeners to the controllers, and broadcast events on login/logout so that controllers would refresh their scope data.

Comment: I tried accessing data in another controller's template and it given me same result e-g i logged in with user1 (it displayed data for user1), logged out and login with user2 (it displayed data for user1 until i refresh the page)..

Comment: but do these controllers get re-created when you relogin? Can you show your app routing code? and html structure.

Comment: And, btw, are they using isolated scopes or a shared one?

Comment: my project's configuration is exactly same is you download it from ionic creator side menu template..

Comment: hmm... yep. looks ok. have you tried to put console.log around the $scope.user initialization line to see its content  and if it is executed 2nd time on relogin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124733/discussion-between-vladimir-m-and-muzafar-ali).

Answer (score 0):

### Use $rootScope:

This problem is mostly due to the menuController being shared by the views and not being reloaded, in such case, you could use `$rootScope.user` which unlike `$scope.user` is shared by all your controllers, use as follows:

**logout controller**

```
.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $rootScope) { // <-- add $rootScope

    // use $rootScope.user instead of $scope.user
    $rootScope.user = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));

    // rest of your code is fine.
    $scope.logout = function(){
        // here i'm removing user from localStorage
        window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
        $state.go('login');
    };
 }
```

**login controller**

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$http', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $http, $rootScope) { // <-- add $rootScope
        // $scope.user = { <-- change to $rootScope
        $rootScope.user = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };

        $scope.login = function(){
            var apiUrl = "...";
            return $http.post(apiUrl, $rootScope.user).then(function(response){
                window.localStorage.setItem('user', angular.toJson(response.data));
                // update $rootScope.user:
                $rootScope.user =  angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
                $state.go('menu.welcome');
            });
        };
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @shadi - will it still work if my views are being cached?

Comment: Do you know any way to reload data in a cached views ?

Comment: View caching is irrelevant to variables used in the view, the variables like `{{user.username}}` should always reflect the most updated values from the scope regardless if the view is cached or not, the view caching is used to avoid reading the markup/html structure every time the view is loaded.

Comment: with $scope data was showing but with $rootScope data is not even showing until i refresh the page!

Comment: make sure to use `$rootScope.user` instead of `$scope.user` in all instances, and add `$rootScope` in controller definition signature as shown above, $rootScope is there to have a $scope that is shared across all your controllers.

Comment: i did use it everywhere and it came up with empty values until refreshed the page!

Answer (score 0):

empty or delete the $scope.user

```
.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$window',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
    $scope.user = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
    $scope.logout = function(){
        // here i'm removing user from localStorage
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
        $state.go('login');

        delete $scope.user;

        /*or $scope.user = {}*/

    };

    $scope.login = function(){
        var apiUrl = "...";
        return $http.post(apiUrl, $rootScope.user).then(function(response){
            $window.localStorage.setItem('user', angular.toJson(response.data));
            // update $rootScope.user:
            $rootScope.user =  angular.fromJson($window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
            $state.go('menu.welcome');
        });
    };
}
])
```

Comment: same effect as - @Shadi Shaaban response! mean on next login all values are empty unless i refresh the page!

Comment: you cannot use window you have to use $window ... i missed that on the first take ... see my edit

Comment: $window or window no difference!